# interaction of different elements of window in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the app with Tkinter, for example:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

class MyMenu(Menu):
    ....

class MyNotebook(Notebook):
    ....

tk=Tk()

f1=Frame(master=tk)
f2=Frame(master=tk)

menu=MyMenu(master=f1)

notebook=MyNotebook(master=f2)
```

I  want to add `command` in `menu`, which will add new tab in `notebook`. How can i do this?

P.S. `f1 != f2` It's important!

P.P.S. functions, that used as `commands` in `menu` may be in another file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the frames is not necessary for the menu, since it should be configured with the window and not placed with the geometry manager. Something similar to this can do the job:

```
# ...
def add_tab():
    text = "Tab {}".format(len(notebook.tabs()))
    frame = Frame(notebook, width=100, height=100)
    notebook.add(frame, text=text)

menu=MyMenu()
menu.add_command(label="Add tab", command=add_tab)
tk.config(menu=menu)
```

However, I recommend you to: a) Define a class instead of using global variables; and b) Don't use `import *` since Tkinter an ttk uses the same name for different classes. It will be not only more organized, but also easier to read:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class MyMenu(tk.Menu):
    pass

class MyNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
    pass

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.notebook = MyNotebook(self.frame)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.notebook.pack()
        self.add_tab()

        menu = MyMenu()
        menu.add_command(label="Add tab", command=self.add_tab)
        self.config(menu=menu)

    def add_tab(self):
        text = "Tab {}".format(len(self.notebook.tabs()))
        frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook, width=100, height=100)
        self.notebook.add(frame, text=text)

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `f1 != f2` condition i placed here to show, that `menu` and `notebook` are not "connected", so, i can't access to `menu` as children of `f2`. And what, if i want put definitions of `comand` functions in another file, so they will be just functions, **not methods of `App`**?

Comment: @user2423017 Two widgets can "interact" as long as you can reference both in your program, so f1!=f2 doesn't matter at all. I wouldn't move the function to another module, because then you then you have the logic of two related things in separate files (even worse than just using global variables).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: for an instance of class A to interact with an instance of class B, class A needs a reference to the instance of class B. That means you need to either pass it in to the constructor, or set if after creation. For example:

```
class MyMenu(Menu):
    def __init__(self, notebook):
        ...
        self.add_command("New page", command=notebook.add(...))
...
notebook = Notebook(...)
menu = MyMenu(notebook)
```

Another way -- which I think is better -- is to pass what is sometimes called a *controller* -- a class that knows about all the widgets, or provides an interface to the widgets. For example, you could implement your app as a class and use an instance of that as your controller:

```
class MyMenu(Menu)
    def __init__(self, app=None):
        ...
        self.add_command(..., command=app.add_tab)

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.menu = MyMenu(self, controller=self)
        self.notebook = Notebook(...)
        ...
    def add_tab(self, label):
        frame = Frame(self)
        self.notebook.add(frame, text=label)

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```